# URL Amigável por titulo

Tags: php, mysql, url, mod-rewrite

Boa noite gente,

Estou aqui a implementar o sistema de url amigável num site e já tenho a funcionar para algumas pagina, estou agora bloqueado no ficheiro ver_estabelecimento que e o que mostra os estabelecimentos neste caso tenho por exemplo um estabelecimento a listar assim `http://exemplo.pt/ver_estabelecimento&id=1` o que eu pretendo e substituir por `http://exemplo.pt/nome_do_estabelecimento` em que o campo nome_do estabelecimento vai vir da base de dados.

Tenho o ficheiro .htaccess condifurado assim:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?m=$1
```

E tenho o meu ficheiro funcoes.php que e onde tenho as regras para incorporar as paginas e mostrar o conteudo o meu problema esta aqui

```
$url = $_GET['m'];
$urlSepara = explode('/',$url);

$primeiraUrl = $urlSepara[0];
$directorio = ("conteudos");

$permissao = array('home', 'comer', 'dormir', 'comprar', 'servicos', 'lazer', 'visitar', 'contactos', 'login', 'erro');

if(!isset($primeiraUrl) || $primeiraUrl == ''){
    include("conteudos/home.php");
}elseif(isset($primeiraUrl) && in_array($primeiraUrl, $permissao)){
    include("".$directorio."/".$primeiraUrl.".php");
}
```

Agradecia ajuda

Comment: Os caminhos (parâmetros) já estão sendo adicionados de maneira correta em seu banco de dados? (Caixa baixa, sem acentos, uso de hífen para separar as palavras, etc)

Comment: sim já não estou a conseguir incorporar as paginas agora

Comment: Eu não sei onde está seu problema realmente - se é na criação de regras, url's, carregar o conteúdo do estabelecimento... Poderia informar mais detalhes?

Comment: O contexto está muito vago. Descreva melhor, coloque mais detalhes de onde está a sua dificuldade.

Comment: Vou explicar melhor qual e o problema

Comment: Você deve usar o seu arquivo htaccess para criar regras de reescrita de URL.

Comment: Como e quero que o nome da url venha do banco de dados não da para fazer a partir do ficheiro funcoes.php com o htaccess assim como esta  ?

Comment: Pode me dar uma ajuda mais precisa para eu saber como posso fazer ?

Comment: Ainda não compreendi o problema. Você esta com dificuldade em criar as rotas ou os links?

Comment: Estou com dificultado ao criar as rotas

Comment: Alguém dar ai uma ajudinha se possível

Comment: é que está tentando pegar pelo $_GET.... vc tem que usar o $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ...

Answer (score 1):

Pode se que seu 'problema' seja mais uma questão de projeto.

Veja que seu array para permissão não forma combinações, com isso você precisa obter a 1ª barra que corresponde a um arquivo que irá analisar barra por barra com uma série de if's.

```
$permissao = array( 'home' , 'comer' , 'dormir' , '...' );

if(!isset($primeiraUrl) || $primeiraUrl == ''){
    include("conteudos/home.php");
}elseif(isset($primeiraUrl) && in_array($primeiraUrl, $permissao)){
    include("".$directorio."/".$primeiraUrl.".php");
}
```

Essa forma é muito poco flexível, o ideal é criar um arquivo tipo config que abstraia as rotas e um arquivo para validar.

Se a URL for `http://exemplo.pt/empresa-x`, então sua variável `$primeiraUrl` terá o valor de *empresa-x*, e isso está fora das suas regras no array `$permissao`.

Uma solução que resolveria seu problema, seria tratar a exceção como página de anúncio. Dessa forma, as URL's `http://exemplo.pt/qualquer-nome-de-empresa` serão aceitas e caberá ao sistema verificar se o anuncio foi encontrado ou não, e continuará funcionando para as outras URL's que você tenha, tipo `http://exemplo.pt/comer/`, `http://exemplo.pt/dormir/`.

<sub>**solução**</sub>

```
if( ! isset( $primeiraUrl ) || $primeiraUrl == '' ) {
    include 'conteudos/home.php';
} elseif( in_array( $primeiraUrl , $permissao ) ) {
    include "{$directorio}/{$primeiraUrl}.php";
} else {
    // $primeiraUrl não está no array, posso SUPOR que seja um anuncio
    // include no arquivo que carrega o anuncio
    // include 'anuncio.php';
}
```

<sub>**anuncio.php**</sub>

```
Verifica no DB se `$primeiraUrl` corresponde a algum anúncio
caso contrário, você apresenta sua mensagem de erro.404
```

<sub>**OBS**, isso resolve o problema, mas não é o ideal. Recomendo que procure sobre rotas no PHP</sub>

---

### <sub>Atualização</sub>

Fazendo o roteamento pelo *.HTACCESS*, você teria que definir todas as rotas possíveis, incluindo a ordem, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# http://exemplo.pt/comer/
RewriteRule ^comer\/$                    index.php?controller=comer&option=index        [QSA,L]

# http://exemplo.pt/comer/camarao/
RewriteRule ^comer\/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)\/  index.php?controller=comer&option=tipo&tipo=$1 [QSA,L]

# http://exemplo.pt/restaurante-do-joao/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)\.html     index.php?controller=anuncio&option=$1         [QSA,L]
```

A vantagem será que você não vai precisar fazer o PHP combinar as possíveis rotas, combinando entrada e saída. Você receberá via `GET` os parâmetros prontos.

Repare que fiz alusão a um sistema baseado em MVC. Não sendo seu caso, então, `controller` representa um arquivo físico que vai trabalhar com o `option`. Tudo vai iniciar pela `index.php`, então um exemplo superficial seria:

---

Para a URL de entrada `http://exemplo.pt/comer/restaurante-do-joao/`, você terá

```
$_GET['controller'] = 'anuncio'
$_GET['option']     = 'restaurante-do-joao'
```

Na sua **index.php** você faz as devidas verificações - que eu omiti - e manda carregar o arquivo correspondente ao controller:

```
//include anuncio.php
include $_GET['controller'] . 'php';
```

No caso do exemplo, será carregado **anuncio.php**, e nele você usa `$_GET['option']` para encontrar o nome da empresa.

Comment: Existe algum framework de rotas que se possa adaptar ao projecto ?

Comment: Não pode dar ai um exemplo de rotas como eu teria que fazer no meu projecto para eu ter uma ideia tenho procurado sobre o assunto mas não encontro nada que me possa ajudar

Comment: @CésarSousa, O [Kohana](https://kohanaframework.org/) tem uma classe que trabalha com as rotas, vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Comment: Tive a ver mas e muito complicado não vou conseguir implementar isso, preciso de algo mais simples que possa por isto a funcionar pois só me falta isto no site

Comment: @CésarSousa, Já pensou em definir as rotas individualmente no *HTACCESS*? Assim você pula o processo de combinação do PHP.

Comment: Não eu nunca fiz nada disto de urls amigáveis e a primeira vez por isso e que estou com grande dificuldade pode me dizer como posso fazer dessa forma ?

Comment: @CésarSousa, inclui os exemplos fazendo as rotas pelo HTACCESS. Se não entender alguma é só perguntar que eu exemplifico melhor.

Comment: E se eu quiser nao mostrar o nome do arquivo e mostrar só o nome correspondente ? e esse nome bem da base de dados

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20985/discussion-between-papa-charlie-and-cesar-sousa).

Comment: Alguem pode ajudar aqui